# How to disable "ActiveX Control May Be Unsafe" popup

Tags: scripting, activex, security-zone

In an HTML file on My Computer, I'm trying to use the Scripting.FileSystemObject in a script. How can I disable the popup saying "Any ActiveX control on this page may be unsafe for scripting"?

The "Internet Options" Security pane allows one to set "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" to Enabled for various zones, but files on the local computer don't appear to be in any of the listed zones.

So I guess the alternate question is "How can I edit the security options for local files?"

System:
  Windows XP SP3
  Internet Explorer 7

Answer (score 17):

By pure hackery, I discovered that setting the following registry value does it:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1201"=dword:00000000
```

But I'm still wondering whether there's any *supported* way of doing this.

Comment: While this registry value doesn't in Windows 7 if you create a DWORD for 1201 with a value of 0 it will correct the issue in that environment as well.

Comment: I am struggling since a while for this, finally I got the solution here, thanks :-). But my problem got solved here  [HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0] "1201="dword:00000000".  I am on windows 10.

Comment: I was looking for a solution in Russian, I had to translate Internet Explorer into English to find this topic and solve the problem. And its works fine for me iIE11 Win 10

Answer (score 8):

Tools |Internet Options | Advanced tab .. way down under Security .. "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer"

Comment: Popup still comes up in IE 9

Answer (score 2):

1. Start Menu, Run and type INETCPL.CPL
2. Click the Security tab
3. In the Internet Zone, click the Custom Level button
4. Set Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe to Allow

Answer (score 1):

There's a [registry way of getting "Local Computer" to appear as one of the security zones](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315933).  But this article doesn't mention IE7, so IE7 might be different.  XP also has new settings like "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" under advanced options.

Alternatively, if you rename your local .html file to .hta (a HMTL application), that might be what you're looking for.  Unless you need all the browser chrome.

Answer (score 1):

as someone mentioned that this should be added to registry 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1201"=dword:00000000

but i found that "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" must be enabled too for internet zone

Comment: Adding site to 'Trusted Zone' and then going into 'custom level' and setting 'Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe' to Enable solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version. Here's for IE32 on x64 Windows:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}\Implemented Categories{7DD95801-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}\Implemented Categories{7DD95802-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}]

Answer (score 0):

I also had ActiveX security warning ("an activex control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction ?") on IE11 Win10 & with the below registry setting I could suppress that popup.

> [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\0] "1201="dword:00000000".

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18 is for **SYSTEM** account & we can also set this for **HKCU** for current user account.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Activex Controls often prompt an error message while trying to launch course through the local files. (For IE7)

Please set the following settings under internet option\Security\Internet\custom level\

1. Run Activex controls and plug ins - Enable
2. Script Activex control marked safe for scripting - Enable
3. under Scripting - Active Scripting - Enable

Also please check the following check box undertools\Internet options\Advanced\security
1. Allow active content to run in my files on my computer.

~Alpana