# How do you avoid the "An ActiveX ... unsafe to interact with other parts of the page" in a Windows Form Application WebBrowser component (VS2019)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I was wondering if it's possible to stop this popup from showing when I run my application? I'm loading external URLs in the HTML loaded in the form's WebBrowser component.

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot]

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate(Application.StartupPath+@"\simple_flash_and_xml_sample\xml_sample.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the registry setting in the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394298/how-to-disable-activex-control-may-be-unsafe-popup

Comment: @stuartd Is there no other way?

Comment: @stuartd tried it, too old can't set it like that.

Comment: It's definitely a security zone issue. [This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users) has lots of technical detail